# what is adverse_event_flag used for?

Tags: openfda

I first tried this query and the returned count of Injury was 9.

https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[19950101+TO+20141231]+AND+device.device_report_product_code:LLZ+AND+product_problem_flag:Y&count=event_type.exact

Then I added the field adverse_event_flag:Y and used the following query. The returned count of injury changed to 6.

https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[19950101+TO+20141231]+AND+device.device_report_product_code:LLZ+AND+product_problem_flag:Y+AND+adverse_event_flag:Y&count=event_type.exact

I thought that, when event_type is Injury, it always indicates that the event has resulted in an adverse outcome in a patient. That is, the count of injuries should be the same by running these two queries. Why does the second query return smaller count? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Reporters fill out a paper form when submitting adverse events to FDA; they may not check the right boxes in all cases.